# replace an svg element with styledtogglebutton

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, material-ui

I have implemented a StyledToggleButton that is very small size. My UX designer has given me a static html page which looks very good but I will need to replace StyledToggleButton with svg? I have tried a few things but am getting no where.

[image]

Left hand-side is the static page, whereas right half is my StyledTogglebutton (AdjustIcon and PlayCircleOutlineIcon). For now I need to put the green play button in place of tiny (black n white) play button which is actually (PlayCircleOutlineIcon).

Green Play button is "Group_33"

**App.js** (static LHS markup)

```
<div className="Custom_Size__12">
      
      <div id="Group_33">
        <svg className="Rectangle_19">
          <rect id="Rectangle_19" rx="229.5" ry="229.5" x={0} y={0} width={459} height={459}>
          </rect>
        </svg>
        <svg className="Polygon_2" viewBox="0 0 217 171">
          <path id="Polygon_2" d="M 98.36752319335938 15.96914386749268 C 103.0805435180664 8.541252136230469 113.9194412231445 8.541252136230469 118.6324615478516 15.96914386749268 L 205.3066864013672 152.5709228515625 C 210.3759765625 160.560302734375 204.6361541748047 171 195.1742248535156 171 L 21.82577323913574 171 C 12.36384773254395 171 6.624013900756836 160.560302734375 11.69330406188965 152.5709228515625 Z">
          </path>
        </svg>
      </div>
       
    </div>
```

**App.js** (react RHS JSX)

```
<Card style={style.main}>
    <CardContent>
      <Stack
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="center"            
        spacing={2}        
      >
        
        <Item><ToggleButton
                value="false"
                selected={pOISelected}
                onChange={onPOISelected}
              >
            <AdjustIcon />
          </ToggleButton></Item> 
          <Item>
          <StyledToggleButton                    
                value="false"
                selected={started}
                onChange={() => {
                       onToggle();          
                }}
              >
              
              
            <PlayCircleOutlineIcon sx={{display: started ? 'none' : 'block'}}/>
            <StopIcon sx={{display: started ? 'block' : 'none' }}/>
          </StyledToggleButton>
        </Item> 
        
                    
      </Stack>
      
      
      </CardContent>
     </Card>
```

How can I replace StyledToggleButton such that functionality stays but look and feel like big green button

I have tried reproducing it in code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-margulis-lx2nx3

Comment: Please use a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it would help others read your code a lot quicker.

Comment: Thanks @BlueRobin I have shared a working example link in codesandbox